# How do I include and link a .dylib file using CMake in VSCode?

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, dylib

I've just started learning how to use CMake and I'm trying to include `glfw` files into my project.

The structure of my project is as follows:

```
main.cpp
CMakeLists.txt
build
dependencies
    - glfw 
        - lib
            - libglfw.3.dylib
        - include
            - glfw3.h
            - glfw3native.h
```

I downloaded the pre-built binaries for MacOS from https://www.glfw.org/download.html and moved the header files and `.dylib` file into my project's directory.

My `CMakeLists.txt` file currently looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)

project(demo)

add_executable(demo main.cpp)

include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dependencies/glfw/include)
link_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dependencies/glfw/lib)

if (APPLE) 
    target_link_libraries(demo PRIVATE
    "-framework OpenGL"
)
endif()

add_library(glfw SHARED IMPORTED)
target_sources(glfw INTERFACE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dependencies/glfw/lib/libglfw.3.dylib)
target_link_libraries(demo INTERFACE glfw)

# set_target_properties(glfw PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dependencies/glfw/lib/libglfw.3.dylib)
```

Running `CMake: Build` on VSCode reports that there are undefined symbols for glfw. I understand that this means I've not linked the library properly, but I do not know where I've went wrong.

My conceptual understanding of CMake is:

- `include_directories` tells CMake where to look for header files, so I can use the `#include` pre-processor directive. This is working perfectly in `main.cpp` where I can `#include <glfw3.h>` and even see IntelliSense hints for the functions and types.
- `link_directories` tells CMake where to look for libraries. It does not actually do the linking, only where to search.
- `add_library(<name> <type> IMPORTED)` "references a library file located outside the project" [[source]](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#command:add_library). It creates the target named `<name>`, making it available in my CMake project. (In this case, the library is technically not 'outside' the project directory, but I thought it didn't matter as I just had to provide the full path to the binary files.)
- `target_sources` specifies which files to use to build a target, a.k.a the source files. I'm not sure if I need to be 'building' the target since it's already a pre-compiled binary, so I thought I did something wrong here. I also tried to use the `set_target_properties` function (commented out) but it didn't work either (still got undefined symbols error).
- Lastly, I link the `glfw` target to my main project's target using `target_link_libraries`. In my head, this tells the linker to link the `glfw` target. And since I specified (1) where to search for the file, and (2) what file to search for, it should work.

Previously, I was using `vcpkg` in my project and installed the glfw files locally. I used

```
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/vcpkg/packages/glfw3_arm64-osx/share/glfw3 ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH})

find_package(glfw3 CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(demo PRIVATE glfw)
target_include_directories(demo PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/vcpkg/packages/glfw3_arm64-osx/include/GLFW)
```

This was actually working perfectly fine but I didn't like the fact that I was linking a static `libglfw3.a` file. I didn't want to statically link the file as I understood that it contributed to overall file size of the executable. I wanted to learn how to link dynamic files properly at runtime.

I really wish to learn how to use CMake well and don't want to be defeated by its apparent complexity. Am I headed in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I was linking the libraries correctly, but I did not set the runtime path (CMAKE_BUILD_RPATH) variable. The compiler required the RPATH to be set so that it can correctly find the `.dylib` files at runtime. Adding one line fixed it.

```
set(CMAKE_BUILD_RPATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dependencies/glfw/lib/libglfw.3.dylib)
```

Now I understand that RPATH is required to find ".dll" files and equivalents.